# How i can add an item that takes value from an angular material form?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cli

I have a dynamic navbar which keep its items in an array. I can add item on it but just static. I want to add item which takes value from the form input area.

This is my .ts file

```
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

MenuItem: MenuItemModels[] = [
{ name : "Home" , link : "#" },
{ name : "About" , link : "#" },
{ name : "School" , link : "#" },
{ name : "Staff" , link : "#" },
{ name : "Contact" , link : "#" }

];
addItem(){

let customObj = new MenuItemModels();
customObj.name = "something";
customObj.link = "#"; 
this.MenuItem.push(customObj);

}
```

This is my Model

```
export class MenuItemModels {

name: any; 
link: any;

}
```

This is my form component it is a different component i want to value from this form inputs and add them on my MenuItemList

```
<div class="example-container">
<mat-form-field>
<input matInput placeholder="Input">
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
<textarea matInput placeholder="Textarea"></textarea>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
<mat-select placeholder="Select">
  <mat-option value="option">Option</mat-option>
</mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use `ReactiveForm` to achieve this: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: please add ur code to stalkblitz

Comment: After can take value from form input area

<p>
  Value: {{ name.value }}
</p> 

i can write it like this in reactive form. But i want to use this value in an other component.

for example
let customObj = new MenuItemModels();
customObj.name = "something";

i want to use Value instead of something. What i should do use in other component ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use that list in other components you can use a *Subject* that you place in a service and on the input `(ngModelChange)=someMethod($event)` you can perform an `customSubject.next(inputValue)` 
and then you are going to read the subject everywhere you want